How can I make something fold, but have specific parts be foldable and others leave unfolded?
When I look at methods to create a folding door or something similar, there is always one parent node that rotates and rotates the rest of the panels/paper to fold, how do I make it so I can fold a segment while keeping some of it flat?
This video for example shows a paper folding in the center it's flat and on the edges they are being folded without being streched.
https://bramfritz.nl/wp-content/uploads/2024/05/paravent_reader_16-9.mp4
Right now I'm using a method where it folds properly with copy rotation and add parent keep transformation such that when I rotate my left most panel, all the other panels update, but how do I make it so I can rotate any panel and have it only affect without it affect the sizing/strecthing of the other panels?



